# How to register an event call a delegated method in a different class using an extension method in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to achieve async data movement between instances of different classes without actually using class references and building an extension method for their base classes instead.

It's a .NET Core Class Library, targeting .NET Standard 1.6.

Let's say I have a class with an `async void` method that continuously updates a property of the same class:

```
public abstract class DataRetriever : DataRetrieverAbstract
{
    public int CollectionInterval { get; private set; }

    public float DataResult { get; private set; }

    private float ReadData()
    {
        return 1; //in reality it returns different values every time
    }

    public async void StartReading(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(CollectionInterval * 1000);
            DataResult = ReadData();
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a second class with an `async void` method which writes the data somewhere:

```
public abstract class DataWriter : DataWriterAbstract
{
    public async void WriteData(float dataToWrite)
    {
        // some writing magic
    }
}
```

How can I build an extension method that basically is going to "pair" **two or more** instances of these classes together and delegate the events?

Something like this:

```
public static DataRetrieverAbstract PairToWriter (this DataRetrieverAbstract retriever, DataWriterAbstract writer)
{
    // ???
}
```

To then use it like this:

```
var dataRetriever1 = new DataRetriever();
var dataRetriever2 = new DataRetriever();
var dataRetriever3 = new DataRetriever();

var dataWriter1 = new DataWriter();
var dataWriter2 = new DataWriter();

dataRetriever1.PairToWriter(dataWriter1).PairToWriter(dataWriter2);
dataRetriever3.PairToWriter(dataWriter2);

// ... stuff goes on
dataRetriever1.StartReading(token);
dataRetriever2.StartReading(token);
dataRetriever3.StartReading(token);
```

So basically we have one `Retriever` writing into two different instances of `DataWriter` and 3-rd `Retriever` using just the second instance.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `async void` stuff is a bit of a red herring, but you could achieve this using an event with multiple subscribers. Internally, this is similar to storing instances of the reader in a list inside the writer. Here's an example:

```
class Program
{
    class DataRetriever
    {
        public event Action<float> DataReady;

        private float ReadData() => 1;

        public async Task StartReading()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                DataReady?.Invoke(ReadData());
            }
        }
    }

    class DataWriter
    {
        public void WriteData(float dataToWrite)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dataToWrite);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var reader1 = new DataRetriever();
        var reader2 = new DataRetriever();
        var reader3 = new DataRetriever();
        var writer1 = new DataWriter();
        var writer2 = new DataWriter();

        reader1.DataReady += writer1.WriteData;
        reader2.DataReady += writer2.WriteData;
        reader3.DataReady += writer2.WriteData;

        Task.Run(reader1.StartReading);
        Task.Run(reader2.StartReading);
        Task.Run(reader3.StartReading);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add some event to base abstract class and subscribe to it. By the way, I suggest to use Task instead of void, because your read/write method can be non completed when your app is finished, so you doesn't "see" the result of these methods:

Here it's `DataRetrieverAbstract` and his derrived class:

```
    public abstract class DataRetrieverAbstract
    {
        public virtual event Action<float> DataReaded;

        protected void FireDataReaded(float arg)
        {
            DataReaded?.Invoke(arg);
        }
    }

    public class DataRetriever : DataRetrieverAbstract
    {
        public int CollectionInterval { get; set; }

        public float DataResult { get; private set; }

        private float ReadData()
        {
            return 1; //in reality it returns different values every time
        }

        public async Task StartReading(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(CollectionInterval * 1000);
                DataResult = ReadData();
            }
            FireDataReaded(DataResult);
        }
    }
```

Next you should move `WriteData` to base class if you want to subscribe on event using base abstract class not derived:

```
    public abstract class DataWriterAbstract
    {
        public abstract void WriteData(float dataToWrite);
    }

    public class DataWriter : DataWriterAbstract
    {
        public override void WriteData(float dataToWrite)
        {
            // some writing magic
            Console.WriteLine(dataToWrite);
        }
    }
```

So your extension is very simple:

```
    public static DataRetrieverAbstract SubscribeOnReaded(this DataRetrieverAbstract retriever, DataWriterAbstract writer)
    {
        retriever.DataReaded += writer.WriteData;
        return retriever;
    }
```

And usage:

```
    var dataRetriever1 = new DataRetriever() { CollectionInterval = 2 };
    var dataRetriever2 = new DataRetriever() { CollectionInterval = 3 };
    var dataRetriever3 = new DataRetriever() { CollectionInterval = 4 };

    var dataWriter1 = new DataWriter();
    var dataWriter2 = new DataWriter();

    dataRetriever1.SubscribeOnReaded(dataWriter1).SubscribeOnReaded(dataWriter2);
    dataRetriever3.SubscribeOnReaded(dataWriter2);

    //...
    CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var tasks = new[] { dataRetriever1.StartReading(source.Token), dataRetriever2.StartReading(source.Token), dataRetriever3.StartReading(source.Token) };

    source.Cancel();
    // If you want to wait a tasks results – uncomment the line below
    //Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```